# Merging CSV and KML in ogr2ogr?

Tags: kml, csv, ogr2ogr

I have a KML file called `tracts.kml` and a CSV called `B01001A_007E_tract.csv` in one directory.

I opened a command line in the folder and ran this:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select tracts.*, B01001A_007E_tract.* from tracts left join 'B01001A_007E_tract.csv'.B01001A_007E_tract on tracts.Id2 = B01001A_007E_tract.StateCountyTractID" dst_tracts.kml tracts.kml
```

I got this message and error:

```
Warning: The target file has a 'kml' extension, which is normally used by the LIBKML, KML drivers,but the requested output driver is ESRI Shapefile. Is it really what you want ?

ERROR 1: SELECT from table tracts failed, no such table/featureclass.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The warning part is simple to fix, just define the outputformat with `-f KML` or `-f LIBKML`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, execute `ogrinfo tracts.kml` in order to keep note of the layer name, e.g. `tracts` (it could be different from the file name). Then append `-f KML` (because your output is a KML file) to the `ogr2ogr` command line and eventually replace `tracts` with the output of `ogrinfo` in the sql query.

Comment: In my case, I appended `-f LIBKML`